# username required message using jquery

Tags: jquery, validation, message

How to put validations in a simple form using "jquery" code?
For eg: if a user does not enter his/her username  then a message will be displayed on client site "enter your username".

Comment: Could you please post your code here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest method

```
 <form id="test">
    Username : <input type="text" id="username"   / >
    Password : <input type="text" id="password"   / >
    <span id="err"></span>
    <input type="button"  id="loginbtn" value="login"/>
    </form>
```

the jQuery code

```
$('#loginbtn').click(function(){
if(username.value===''){
err.innerHTML='Username is a required field';
return false;
}

if(password.value===''){
err.innerHTML='password is a required field';
return false;
}
)};
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the jquery validation plugin
http://jqueryvalidation.org/